# Template __host__ __device__ calling host defined functions

Tags: cuda

During implementation of CUDA code I often need some utility functions, which will be called from device and also from host code. So I declare these functions as **__host__ __device__**. This is OK and possible device/host incompabilities can be handled by **#ifdef CUDA_ARCH**.

Problems come when the utility function is templated ie. by some functor type. If the template instance calls a **__host__** function I get this warning:

```
calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed
      detected during instantiation of "int foo(const T &) [with T=HostObject]"
```

Only solution I know is to define the function twice - once for device and once for host code with different name (I cannot overload on `__host__ __device__`). But this means that there is code duplication and all other `__host__ __device__` functions which will call it, must be also defined twice (even more code duplication).

**Simplified example:**

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <iostream>

struct HostObject {
    __host__ 
    int value() const { return 42; }
};

struct DeviceObject {
    __device__ 
    int value() const { return 3; }
};

template <typename T> 
__host__ __device__ 
int foo(const T &obj) {
    return obj.value();
}

/*
template <typename T> 
__host__ 
int foo_host(const T &obj) {
    return obj.value();
}

template <typename T> 
__device__ 
int foo_device(const T &obj) {
    return obj.value();
}
*/

__global__ void kernel(int *data) {
    data[threadIdx.x] = foo(DeviceObject());
}

int main() {
    foo(HostObject());

    int *data;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&data, sizeof(int) * 64);
    kernel<<<1, 64>>>(data);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    cudaFree(data);
}
```

Warning is caused by the `foo(HostObject());` call inside the `main()` function.

`foo_host<>` and `foo_device<>` are possible replacements for the problematic `foo<>`.

Is there a better solution? Can I prevent instantion of `foo()` on the device side?

Comment: No constructor is called inside `foo()`. Problem is exactly what the warning says. I am asking if I can somehow fix it without defining the generic function twice.

Comment: The warning is caused by `foo(HostObject())` in the main function. There is no problem with constructors because until I declare one by myself there will be automatically generated constructors (by both host and device compilers).

Comment: Sorry, now I see your point - not so easy to see where the error is shown without a compiler. It would be therefore useful to mention it in your question I believe.

Comment: I guess it is just a compiler problem. Thrust uses templates excessively and disables this kind of warnings using `#pragma hd_warning_disable`, see https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/thrust/detail/config/hd_warning_disable.h

Comment: So far the best solution. Only problem with this is that when you do the mistake of using host function in the device code you loose the warning.

Comment: You do not globally disable the warning, you need to use this `#pragma` for every template function, have a look at https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/thrust/iterator/detail/zip_iterator_base.h for example.

Comment: I know that it does not hide the warning globally. But even in the simple example if I call `foo(HostObject())` inside the kernel (which is wrong) the warning would be useful. But still better than nothing - thank you for the tip.

Comment: I'm puzzled.  What's the objection to marking `value()` (in `HostObject`) as `__host__ __device__` ?

Comment: Imagine that HostObject is not not under your control - it may come from different library or module, so you cannot make it CUDA enabled. Also it would mean that CUDA compiler would process the function and if the body is not compilable by CUDA compiler it would spawn error messages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot prevent instantiation of either half of a `__host__ __device__` function template instantiation. If you instantiate the function by calling it on the host (device), the compiler will also instantiate the device (host) half.

The best you can do for your use case as of CUDA 7.0 is to suppress the warning using `#pragma hd_warning_disable` as in the following example and ensure that the function is not called incorrectly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

#pragma hd_warning_disable
template<class Function>
__host__ __device__
void invoke(Function f)
{
  f();
}

struct host_only
{
  __host__
  void operator()()
  {
    std::cout << "host_only()" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct device_only
{
  __device__
  void operator()()
  {
    printf("device_only(): thread %d\n", threadIdx.x);
  }
};

__global__
void kernel()
{
  // use from device with device functor
  invoke(device_only());

  // XXX error
  // invoke(host_only());
}

int main()
{
  // use from host with host functor
  invoke(host_only());

  kernel<<<1,1>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  // XXX error
  // invoke(device_only());

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know if `#pragma hd_warning_disable` or `#pragma nv_exec_check_disable` are documented anywhere ?

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same problem, and found half of a solution. One can overload the host and device function by adding dummy template parameters to them.

In device code, the `__device__` "overload" of `f` is called, in `host` code the `__host__` "overload" of `f` is called.

Unfortunately, this makes `f` to a template function. In particular, for constructors this can make big problems (which I am still struggling with).

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdio>

#ifndef __CUDA_ARCH__
    static constexpr bool in_cuda_code = false;
#else
    static constexpr bool in_cuda_code = true;
#endif
    
__device__ void g_device() { printf( "device\n" ); };
__host__   void g_host() { printf( "host\n" ); };

template< bool b = in_cuda_code > void f();
template<> __device__ void f<true>() { g_device(); }  
template<> __host__ void f<false>() { g_host(); }

__global__ void kernel () {
    f();
}

int main() {
    f();
    kernel<<<1,1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```