# creating Thrust::device_vectors in a __host__ __device__ functor

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, thrust

I am currently trying to parallelize thrust cuda code that currently runs sequentially in a main function (and therefore does not harness the power of the GPU). I have essentially taken functional code an put it into a functor that thrust::for_each can call using cuda streams. However if I define the functor using

```
__host__ __device__
```

VS2013 throws all sorts of warnings saying that I am trying to launch host functions from the device. These errors are occurring in places were I am defining a vector using

```
thrust::device_vector vect (size_vector);
```

as well as some thrust::transform functions. It specifically quotes problems with the thrust::device_malloc_allocator. If I define the functor as strictly a **host** functor these errors all go away, however when I use the profiler it becomes evident that only 0.01% of the device is being used leading me to believe for_each is not actually launching the thrust code in the functor.

**EDIT**
below is some code that compiles and shows this error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/for_each.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <thread>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>


using namespace std;

const int num_segs = 1;  // number of segments to sort
const int num_vals = 5;  // number of values in each segment


template <typename T> 
struct sort_vector
{
    T *Ddata;
    T *vect3;
    T *answer;

    sort_vector(T *_Ddata, T *_vect3, float *a) : Ddata(_Ddata), vect3(_vect3), answer(a) {};


    __host__ __device__ void operator()(int idx)
    {
        thrust::sort(thrust::seq, Ddata + idx*num_vals, Ddata + ((idx + 1)*num_vals));
        thrust::device_ptr<float> vect3_ptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(vect3);
        thrust::device_vector<float> vect(10, 1);
        thrust::device_vector<float> vect2(10, 3);
        thrust::transform(thrust::device, vect.begin(), vect.end(), vect2.begin(), vect3_ptr, thrust::minus<float>());
        *answer = thrust::reduce(thrust::device, Ddata + idx*num_vals, Ddata + ((idx + 1)*num_vals));

    }
};

int main() {

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_Ddata(num_segs*num_vals);
    d_Ddata[0] = 50;
    d_Ddata[1] = 9.5;
    d_Ddata[2] = 30;
    d_Ddata[3] = 8.1;
    d_Ddata[4] = 1;

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_Ddata2(num_segs*num_vals);
    d_Ddata2[0] = 50;
    d_Ddata2[1] = 20.5;
    d_Ddata2[2] = 70;
    d_Ddata2[3] = 8.1;
    d_Ddata2[4] = 1;

    thrust::device_vector<float> vect3(10, 0);
    thrust::device_vector<float> vect4(10, 0);

    cout << "original dut" << endl;
    int g = 0;
        while (g < num_segs*num_vals){
            cout << d_Ddata[g] << endl;
            g++;
        }

        thrust::device_vector<int> d_idxs(num_segs);
        thrust::sequence(d_idxs.begin(), d_idxs.end());

        thrust::device_vector<float> dv_answer(1);
        thrust::device_vector<float> dv_answer2(1);
        cudaStream_t s1, s2;
        cudaStreamCreate(&s1);
        cudaStreamCreate(&s2);

        clock_t start;
        double duration;
        start = clock();

        thrust::for_each(thrust::cuda::par.on(s1),
            d_idxs.begin(),
            d_idxs.end(), sort_vector<float>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_Ddata.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(vect3.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(dv_answer.data())));

        thrust::for_each(thrust::cuda::par.on(s2),
            d_idxs.begin(),
            d_idxs.end(), sort_vector<float>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_Ddata2.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(vect4.data()), thrust::raw_pointer_cast(dv_answer2.data())));

        cudaStreamSynchronize(s1);
        cudaStreamSynchronize(s2);

        cout << "sorted dut" << endl;
        int n = 0;
        while (n < num_segs*num_vals){
            cout << d_Ddata[n] << endl;
            n++;
        } 
        cout << "sum" << endl;
        cout << dv_answer[0] << endl;
        cout << dv_answer2[0] << endl;

        cout << "vector subtraction" << endl;
        int e = 0;
        while (e < 10){
            cout << vect3[e] << endl;
            e++;
        }

        cudaStreamDestroy(s1);
        cudaStreamDestroy(s2);

        duration = (clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        cout << "time " << duration << endl;

        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
```

Is it possible that thrust::for_each cannot call `__host__` functors?

Are some thrust calls innately connected to the host behind the scenes?

The only potential workaround I can see is creating a `__host__ __device__` fucntor that has separate host and device defined code within it. It is also possible that I have missed something while researching this subject. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You many want to create a MCVE code to reproduce your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> These errors are occurring in places were I am defining a vector

As the compiler is clearly telling you, the problem is that the constructor and all the operators defined within `thrust::vector` are currently *host only* functions. It is illegal to try to use them in a `__device__`function.

There is no solution other than not attempting to instantiate a vector within device code.

Comment: Yes, this was what I thought was the problem. However, changing it to host code causes the for_each call to fail and not call the functor at all. So what you're saying is that there is no work around? Maybe something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30029197/template-host-device-calling-host-defined-functions

Comment: @gracie: The workaround *in the code you have now posted* is to remove the device vector from the functor. You are not even using it for anything.

Comment: I realize it isn't doing anything in the code I've posted. It was just an example to show the warnings this action creates, since I'm trying to use this technique in a much larger program.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't provide you with a solution to a problem I can't see. If you post a non-representative question with a non-representative example, you cannot reasonably expect an exact answer.

Comment: I've updated the code in an attempt to make it more representative.

Answer (score -3):

Thrust provides a host and a device path for all its algorithms but algorithms can only be launched from the host.

At compile time, Thrust looks at the types of the iterators to determine which path to build. If it builds a device path, then the same restrictions apply as for regular CUDA code, one of which is that device code cannot call functions on the host.

So, a statement like `thrust::sort()` launches an algorithm and can only exist in host code. At compile time, the iterators passed to `sort()` are examined and the Thrust templates are used for building either a host or a device version of `sort()` that handles your particular types. If a device version is built and it takes a functor, it must also be possible to build a device version of the functor, which means that the functor can't contain a Thrust statement that launches a new algorithm.

At runtime, the device version of a statement like `thrust::sort()` will launch one or more CUDA kernels, so what you might want to look into is Thrust's ability to combine separate algorithms into the same kernel, which Thrust calls kernel fusion. There are a couple of ways to do this, one of which is to use a transform iterator. See the Thrust docs for details.

Comment: Thrust algorithms can be launched from device code.  This answer is incorrect.  OP has already asked several questions demonstrating that thrust algorithms can be launched from device code.

Comment: I can clearly see that some can be launched from device code, but it seems like some cannot. Is it just that some cannot (at least in the form I'm using) specifically transforms and device vector allocations? Are these set up differently in the library? I tried to send the thrust::device and also the thrust::seq flag and it still threw a bunch of errors and did not work.

Comment: A device vector is not an algorithm.  You may want to read the thrust quick start guide.  `thrust::device_vector` (which is a *container*, not an *algorithm*) cannot be used in device code, as the other answer already indicated to you.  And, no, `thrust::for_each` (or any algorithm) cannot use a `__host__` (only) functor, if the algorithm is working with device data.

Comment: Oh, I see. This makes much more sense now. Also when the containers are properly passed in the errors for the thrust::transform also goes away. So this solves my problem. Thank you.