# How to disable Cuda host device warning for just one function?

Tags: c++, cuda, closures, c++14, pragma

I've got a C++14 template in my Cuda code that is templated over a lambda closure and is `__host__` and `__device__` and I get the warning:

```
warning: calling a __host__ function("Iter<(bool)1> ::Iter [subobject]")
         from a __host__ __device__ function("Horizontal::Horizontal")
         is not allowed
```

But this is a false positive, because it is only the `__host__` instantiation of the template that calls the `__host__` function, so I wish to suppress this warning for just this one template definition.

I can add this before the template:

```
#pragma hd_warning_disable
```

And the warning goes away, however, I'm concerned that I only want it suppressed for this one template function, not the remaining of the compilation unit.  I cannot easily move the template function to the end of the compilation unit.

I'd like some kind of push and pop but I'm not finding this anywhere.

Is there a way to reenable hd warnings with a pragma after the template function is defined?

I tried:

```
#pragma hd_warning_enable
```

But that doesn't work:

```
test.cu:44:0: warning: ignoring #pragma 
hd_warning_enable  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma hd_warning_enable
```

Here is simple test case to demonstrate the issue:

```
//#pragma hd_warning_disable

template<typename Lambda>
__host__ __device__
int hostDeviceFunction(const Lambda lambda)
{
    return lambda();
}


__device__
int deviceFunction()
{
    auto lambda = []() { return 0.0; };

    return hostDeviceFunction( lambda );
}

__host__
int hostFunction()
{
    auto lambda = []() { return 1.0; };

    return hostDeviceFunction( lambda );
}
```

Which gives these warnings:

```
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed
          detected during instantiation of "int hostDeviceFunction(Lambda) [with Lambda=lambda []()->double]" 
(24): here
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function(" const") from a __host__ __device__ function("hostDeviceFunction< ::> ") is not allowed
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed
          detected during instantiation of "int hostDeviceFunction(Lambda) [with Lambda=lambda []()->double]" 
(24): here
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function(" const") from a __host__ __device__ function("hostDeviceFunction< ::> ") is not allowed
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed
          detected during instantiation of "int hostDeviceFunction(Lambda) [with Lambda=lambda []()->double]" 
(24): here
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function(" const") from a __host__ __device__ function("hostDeviceFunction< ::> ") is not allowed
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed
          detected during instantiation of "int hostDeviceFunction(Lambda) [with Lambda=lambda []()->double]" 
(24): here
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function(" const") from a __host__ __device__ function("hostDeviceFunction< ::> ") is not allowed
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed
          detected during instantiation of "int hostDeviceFunction(Lambda) [with Lambda=lambda []()->double]" 
(24): here
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function(" const") from a __host__ __device__ function("hostDeviceFunction< ::> ") is not allowed
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed
          detected during instantiation of "int hostDeviceFunction(Lambda) [with Lambda=lambda []()->double]" 
(24): here
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function(" const") from a __host__ __device__ function("hostDeviceFunction< ::> ") is not allowed
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed
          detected during instantiation of "int hostDeviceFunction(Lambda) [with Lambda=lambda []()->double]" 
(24): here
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function(" const") from a __host__ __device__ function("hostDeviceFunction< ::> ") is not allowed
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed
          detected during instantiation of "int hostDeviceFunction(Lambda) [with Lambda=lambda []()->double]" 
(24): here
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function(" const") from a __host__ __device__ function("hostDeviceFunction< ::> ") is not allowed
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed
          detected during instantiation of "int hostDeviceFunction(Lambda) [with Lambda=lambda []()->double]" 
(24): here
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function(" const") from a __host__ __device__ function("hostDeviceFunction< ::> ") is not allowed
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed
          detected during instantiation of "int hostDeviceFunction(Lambda) [with Lambda=lambda []()->double]" 
(24): here
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function(" const") from a __host__ __device__ function("hostDeviceFunction< ::> ") is not allowed
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed
          detected during instantiation of "int hostDeviceFunction(Lambda) [with Lambda=lambda []()->double]" 
(24): here
test.cu(7): warning: calling a __host__ function(" const") from a __host__ __device__ function("hostDeviceFunction< ::> ") is not allowed
```

Comment: You could also consider restructuring your code to avoid the warning instead of suppressing it. *I* would, personally, try that option *first*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, I tried, but failed to do so.

Comment: The pragma only suppresses the warnings for the one function it's in front of. At least that's the case for me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for something like `#pragma hd_warning_enable` as `#pragma hd_warning_disable` only affects the function it is placed in front of.
As it seems this is nothing one can find in any documentation but the example below suggests that behavior.

Sidenote:
There is also `#pragma nv_exec_check_disable` and popular libraries have migrated to that pragma.
See e.g. [this conversation](https://github.com/ComputationalRadiationPhysics/picongpu/pull/1707) about it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

#pragma hd_warning_disable
//#pragma nv_exec_check_disable
template<typename Lambda>
__host__ __device__
int hostDeviceFunction1(const Lambda lambda)
{
    return lambda()*1.0;
}

__host__            
int hostFunction1()
{
    auto lambda = []() { return 1.0; };  
    return hostDeviceFunction1( lambda );
}

template<typename Lambda>
__host__ __device__
int hostDeviceFunction2(const Lambda lambda)
{                                       
    return lambda()*2.0;
}

__host__
int hostFunction2()
{
    auto lambda = []() { return 2.0; };  
    return hostDeviceFunction2( lambda );
}

int main()           
{ 
  std::cout << "hostFunction1: " << hostFunction1() << std::endl;
  assert(hostFunction1() == 1.0);

  std::cout << "hostFunction2: " << hostFunction2() << std::endl;
  assert(hostFunction2() == 4.0);

  return 0;
}
```

```
$ nvcc pragma_test.cu 
pragma_test.cu(24): warning: calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed
          detected during instantiation of "int hostDeviceFunction2(Lambda) [with Lambda=lambda []()->double]" 
(31): here
```

Comment: If anyone finds the documentation about (any of) theses pragmas please tell us. There is also an [open question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49328130/7968757) about it.

Comment: I've confirmed that `#pragma nv_exec_check_disable` only affects the following function.

Comment: Be careful, both `nv_exec_check_disable` and `hd_warning_disable` pragmas makes my nvcc 11.2 generate *wrong* code. This is also reported here https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/pragma-hd-warning-disable-causes-nvcc-to-generate-incorrect-code-cuda-9-1/57755 . Given that, they are not useful for my case, having the warning displayed and working code seems preferable. Also, ` --diag_suppress=20014` does nothing in my case (warning still shown).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to avoid the warning in some cases is to make the lower-level function `constexpr` and use the `--expt-relaxed-constexpr` flag.

For example:

```cpp
template<typename Lambda>
constexpr int constexprFunction(Lambda&& lambda)
{
    return lambda();
}


__host__
int hostFunction()
{
    auto lambda = []() { return 1.0; };
    return constexprFunction( lambda );
}

__host__ __device__
int hostDeviceFunction()
{
    auto lambda = []() { return 0.0; };
    return constexprFunction( lambda );
}
```

Compared to the undocumented pragmas, this has the advantage that the effects of `constexpr` are exactly documented, although the exact behaviour of `nvcc` is still undocumented and its conformance to the standards is not 100%. For instance, the example above works with `nvcc` 10.1.243 in C++14 mode, but not in C++11. And if you change the signature of the function to `constexpr int constexprFunction(const Lambda lambda)`, the warning still appears, so `--expt-relaxed-constexpr` does not seem to do its thing in all cases. And if you add a `__device__` function, it results in an error either way:

```cpp
__device__
int deviceFunction()
{
    auto lambda = []() { return 0.0; };
    return constexprFunction( lambda );
}
```

Comment: These seems to have changed with cuda 12/C++20. I can compile the device function without problems.